# Putting array into table and grid form - PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array of item code, item name, and price

```
$arr = array(
    "101: orange juice - 5.2",
    "504: hot roll - 6.2",
    "106: lime juice - 3",
    "210: mineral water (s) - 2.6",
    "107: PEACH JUICE - 6.99",
    "211: mineral water (m) - 3.7",
    "500: hot dog (r) - 3.7",
    "212: mineral water (l) - 4.9",
    "509: popcorn - 4.2",
    "501: HOT DOG (l) - 5.1",
    "502: apple pie - 12.69",
    "100: apple juice - 4.8",
    "506: pine tart - 0.75",
    "108: coca COLA - 3.25",
);
```

How can I sort the array from the original form, make it to lowercase, put into a table and add "RM" in front of the price with 2 floats behind, like

[image: Image A]

And at the same time putting it into a grid layout format like[image: Image B].

Trying to play around with PHP array to familiarize myself but I am only able to do it if I re-declare the array with Code, Name, Price specified, like

```
$arr1 = array(
array(Item_Code=>101, Item_Name=>"orange juice",Price=>5.2),
...
)
```

Comment: if you can redeclare your array then that is the easiest solution.What you want now?

Comment: Let's just say i don't want to re-declare it, since this is a small array, i only re-declare, but is there any other way to do like in the image?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    "101: orange juice - 5.2",
    "504: hot roll - 6.2",
    "106: lime juice - 3",
    "210: mineral water (s) - 2.6",
    "107: PEACH JUICE - 6.99",
    "211: mineral water (m) - 3.7",
    "500: hot dog (r) - 3.7",
    "212: mineral water (l) - 4.9",
    "509: popcorn - 4.2",
    "501: HOT DOG (l) - 5.1",
    "502: apple pie - 12.69",
    "100: apple juice - 4.8",
    "506: pine tart - 0.75",
    "108: coca COLA - 3.25",
);



$formattedAry = array();
foreach($arr as $a){
  $newArray = array();
  list($code, $namePrice) = explode(":", $a);
  list($name, $price) = explode("-", $namePrice);
  $newArray['Item_Code'] = trim($code);
  $newArray['Item_Name'] = trim($name);
  $newArray['Price'] = trim($price);
  $formattedAry[] = $newArray;
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($formattedAry);
?>
```

Comment: @LSY.E is this helpfull??

Comment: it works correctly. you have to include the html blocks

Comment: @kranthi thanks, now im trying to put into the grid layout, you have any idea how do i put into it like in the second picture, I am only able to put into the table like in the first picture

Comment: @LSY.E:  try to provide what you tried for second format

Comment: @kranthi to be honest, i really don't know how to, i only know how to create a hard-coded grid-layout, don't have any idea how to actually pull out from array and put into the grid-layout

Comment: @LSY.E: try to learn it.....first create hard-coded grid-layout then try to make  dynamic.......i can help you if you stuck in middle...